# Elastic Beanstalk CLI: The system cannot find the file specified: '.elasticbeanstalk\\'

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebcli

I am attempting to follow the instructions here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html

but when running `eb init`, I get `ERROR: FileNotFoundError - [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '.elasticbeanstalk\\'`.

I installed the cli using these instructions:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install-windows.html

Edit:

```
eb --version
EB CLI 3.20.7 (Python 3.11.4 (tags/v3.11.4:d2340ef, Jun  7 2023, 05:45:37) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)])
```

Comment: are you able to run `eb --version`?

Comment: I followed the docs steps in my window machine, it working fine for me.

Comment: Maybe try with admin user